# How do I optimize my trigger using math?

Tags: sql-server, math, triggers, case

I have a problem with my trigger, it looks like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Balance_monthly]
ON [dbo].[Balance]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    UPDATE Months
    SET Months.Balance_monthly = 
        CASE 
            WHEN Balance.In_Months > 1 THEN Amount_Monthly          
        END
    FROM Balance
    JOIN Months 
    ON Months.Id <= Balance.In_Months;

    UPDATE Months
    SET Months.Balance_monthly = 
    CASE 
        WHEN Balance.In_Months >= 13 THEN Amount_Monthly * 2        
    END
    FROM Balance
    JOIN Months 
    ON Months.Id <= Balance.In_Months - 12;

    UPDATE Months
    SET Months.Balance_monthly = 
    CASE 
        WHEN Balance.In_Months >= 25 THEN Amount_Monthly * 3        
    END
    FROM Balance
    JOIN Months 
    ON Months.Id <= Balance.In_Months - 24;

END
```

This is the table where my trigger is stored, there is only 1 row and it will stay that way so don't think about that.
[image: My table]

This is the table that I put the values into depending on how many In_Months there is.
[image: My other table]

As you can see, this is working perfectly untill the In_Months get over 37. My question is if there's any smart heads out there who could help me on how to make this calculate it no matter how many In_Months there is.

Comment: What's the logic where `> 1` is used in the first comparison, but `>= 13`, `>= 25` etc in the other comparisons?

Comment: if`> 1` then it just takes it directly from Amount_Monthly, but if it's`>= 13`then it has to `*2`

Comment: No, I mean why is the first comparison "Greater than" and all of the other comparisons "Greater than or equal"? What is the code meant to do if `In_Months` is exactly 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* that this expression should compute what you want:

```
UPDATE Months
SET Months.Balance_monthly = 
    ((Balance.In_Months + 12 - Months.Id) / 12) * Amount_Monthly          
FROM Balance
CROSS JOIN Months;
```

On the assumption that, if `In_Months` is 1, we *should* be setting a value for January.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thank you math genius!

Comment: Can you explain what the `CROSS JOIN` does in this situation? I can't find anything on google that explains it.

Comment: I removed the `CROSS JOIN` because it seems unnecessary.

Comment: @Bungicasse - the `cross join` is being used here to make it explicit that there's no relation between `Balance` and `Months` - we want all (1) rows of `Balance` to be joined with all (12) rows of `Months`.

Comment: but it works without it so I don't really understand

Comment: @Bungicasse - it's not *technically* required, but if an experienced SQL developer encounters pre-ANSI joins (`FROM Balance, Months`), they will tend to assume that the author doesn't know what they're doing. Especially, as here, where there's no `WHERE` clause and so we are producing a Cartesian join, a common source of beginner errors in SQL. So, it's an explicit indication to any later reviewers of this code - "this is a Cartesian join right here, and that's *what I wanted*"